# Reasons of using GC param::: -XX:LoopUnrollLimit=0?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, garbage

Our application have below property running since long in PROD since JDK 1.4, we had added it to work around some bug in memory that time:

```
-XX:LoopUnrollLimit=0
```

However we upgraded to JDK 1.6, and seems like this option will make program slow for no good reason.

Any guidance is appreciated, should we remove it?

Comment: That parameter is not GC-related, it's used by the JIT compilers.

Comment: Thanks, can you please help whether we can remove it in JDK 1.6?

Answer (score 0):

> work around some bug in memory

Do you have test-case for that bug? If so, just run it against 1.6 (btw, that already reached end-of-life) and see if it occurs or not. If your particular problem has been solved there should be no reason not to use default options, especially if they deliver better performance.